# Does a series solution to a transcendental equation always converge or can it diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, transcendental-equations

Suppose an arbitrary transcendental equation like
$$\phi(u,z) = 0 \quad .$$
To find "*analytically*" the solution $u=u(z)$ that satisfies this I consider an expansion around small $z$ and produce a series expansion.

**First inquiry**: Do transcendental equations always allow some kind of expansion?

**Second inquiry**: The series produced by a transcendental equation is always convergent or can it be divergent?

I am interested to know some examples where a transcendental equation produces a divergent series (zero radii of convergence) or if there is some theorem that prohibits this.

---

I am asking this because I looked at two simple scenarios where the series has a finite radius of convergence and I am curious whether this is a general thing.

The scenarios I looked where
$$ u e^u = z,$$
which produces a convergent series around $z=0$ and we also know the exact answer as the Lambert W function, $u = W(z)$.

And also,
$$ -z e^u + \ln u = 0 \Rightarrow e^{-ze^u} u =1$$
which does not produce a named function but can be represented either by a convergent series around $z=0$ or by the *continued exponential*
$$ u = e^{ze^{ze^{ze^{...}}}}$$

Comment: For an example of a transcendental function with powerseries which has zero radius of convergence look at the *"half-iterate of the function"* $f(z)=\exp(z)$ where the *half-iterate* is $h(z)$ with $h(h(z))=f(z)$. The leading coefficients are well known and may be found even in wikipedia; the proof of zero-radius of convergence is due to I.N.Baker and as well discussed by Erdoes. However I have computed and discussed that series in some unusual depth/detail and have some of the results on the "tetration"-part of my homepage http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/index.htm

Comment: ... the perhaps most relevant/direct link is there this one: http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/htmltable_utetrationFractionalIteration.htm